# Search fields in multiple models in Django

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-rest-framework

Suppose,

A model named `Education` contains the fields `degree` and `field`, and other model `Resume` contains the fields `skill` and `role`.

A third model is `Candidates` and has a foreign key relation with the above models.

I want the user to search candidates by their `skill`, `role`, `degree` or `field`.

For example: if a query string like `{'java','developer','MS','IT'}` is passed, Django should show the all the candidates matching any one of the values in the query string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you're doing this with the Django Rest Framework (DRF), you will want to use [django_filters](https://django-filter.readthedocs.org/en/latest/) as [referenced by DRF](http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend).

To do what you're talking about in my project, I created a generic extension of a `django_filters.Filter`:

```
import operator
from django.db.models import Q
import django_filters

class MultiFieldFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def __init__(self,names,*args,**kwargs):
        if len(args) == 0:
            kwargs['name'] = names[0]
        self.token_prefix = kwargs.pop('token_prefix','')
        self.token_suffix = kwargs.pop('token_suffix','')
        self.token_reducer = kwargs.pop('token_reducer',operator.and_)
        self.names = names
        django_filters.Filter.__init__(self,*args,**kwargs)

    def filter(self,qs,value):
        if value not in (None,''):
            tokens = value.split(',')
            return qs.filter(
                reduce(
                    self.token_reducer,
                    [
                        reduce(
                            operator.or_,
                            [Q(**{
                                '%s__icontains'%name:
                                    (self.token_prefix+token+self.token_suffix)})
                                        for name in self.names])
                        for token in tokens]))
        return qs
```

This is used in a `django_filter.FilterSet` like this:

```
class SampleSetFilter(django_filters.FilterSet):
    multi_field_search = MultiFieldFilter(names=["field_foo", "bar", "baz"],lookup_type='in')
    class Meta:
        model = SampleSet
        fields = ('multi_field_srch',)
```

Which is instantiated like:

```
 class SampleSetViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    queryset = SampleSet.objects.all()
    serializer_class = SampleSetSerializer
    filter_class = SampleSetFilterSet # <- and vvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvvv
    filter_backends = (filters.OrderingFilter, filters.DjangoFilterBackend,)
```

Finally, a `GET` request like:

```
http://www.example.com/rest/SampleSet/?multi_field_srch=foo,de,fa,fa
```

will return all `SampleSet`'s that have *all* of `foo`, `de`, *and* `fa` in at least one of the fields `field_foo`, `bar`, or `baz`.

If you specify parameter `token_reducer` to be `operator.or_`, then that query would return all `SampleSet`s that have *any* of `foo`, `de`, *or* `fa` in at least one of the fields `field_foo`, `bar`, or `baz`.

Finally, `token_prefix` and `token_suffix` are a way to insert wild cards (substring matching) or other prefixes or suffixes.

Answer (score 1):

I don't think there's an automatic way to do this in django. But you can always OR multiple searches together using Q. The basic usage of Q is as follows:

```
from django.db.models import Q
Education.objects.filter(
    Q(degree__icontains=query) | Q(field__icontains=query)
```

To use multiple queries you can easily build together these statements using a for statement (assuming queries is a list or set of query strings):

```
q = Q()
for query in queries
    q = q | Q(degree__icontains=query) | Q(field__icontains=query)
Education.objects.filter(q)
```

Now you'd want to search over multiple models, so you would have to include those joins as well. It's not exactly clear from your question how you'd want to search, but I'd guess you'd like to basically search for candidates and that all keywords need to be matched by the found items. So the query could be done like this:

```
q = Q() 
for query in queries
    q = (q & (Q(education__degree__icontains=query) | 
              Q(education__field__icontains=query)  |
              Q(resume__skill__icontains=query) |
              Q(resume__role__icontains=query)
              Q(skill__icontains=query) |
              Q(role__icontains=query) |
              Q(degree__icontains=query) |
              Q(field__icontains=query)))
return Candidate.objects.filter(q)
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm using [Django Rest Multiple Models](https://github.com/MattBroach/DjangoRestMultipleModels) to search on multiple models in Django Rest Framework. Make sure to read the docs carefully, especially the [section on using viewsets](https://django-rest-multiple-models.readthedocs.io/en/latest/viewsets.html) which explains how to set up your endpoints. It seems really well built and documented, and to support everything I expect such as limits and filters.