# Django FilterSet AND(?) condition

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework

I am creating an application where food has several components, and each component has a specific value. I want to be able to filter food for the value of a specific component.

Here are my models:

```
class Food(models.Model):
    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="id")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    product_type = models.CharField(max_length=150)

class Component(models.Model):

    id = models.AutoField(primary_key=True, db_column="id")
    name = models.CharField(max_length=150)
    value = models.FloatField()
    food = models.ForeignKey(Food, related_name='food_components', related_query_name='food_components')
```

Then I define filter sets and the view

```
import rest_framework_filters as filters

class ComponentFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    name = filters.CharFilter(name="name")
    val = filters.NumberFilter(name="value", distinct=True)
    minval = filters.NumberFilter(name="value", lookup_type="gte", distinct=True)
    maxval = filters.NumberFilter(name="value", lookup_type="lte", distinct=True)

    class Meta:
        model = Component

class FoodFilter(filters.FilterSet):

    name = filters.CharFilter(name='name')
    product_type = filters.CharFilter(name='product_type')
    components = filters.RelatedFilter(ComponentFilter, name='food_components')

    class Meta:
        model = Food

class FoodViewSet(viewsets.ModelViewSet):

    queryset = Food.objects.all()
    serializer_class = FoodSerializer
    filter_class = FoodFilter
```

I want to be able to filter a viewset using more than one field in a related model (combining both parameters). Something like http://whatever/foods/components__name=X&components__value=1 would get me all foods with the element X of value 1. I am using django-rest-framework-filters (https://github.com/philipn/django-rest-framework-filters)

From what I see, since all foods have all the elements, the components__name is irrelevant, and I will get all the foods that have any component with the value 1. How can I combine both?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Are you looking for a multi-field filter like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/a/31009472/20712)?

Comment: From what I understand of the example you provided, that will return any fields containing those values (more a less like an OR relation), while I am interested in being able to specify two filters in one URL, but having them be combined like an AND condition.

Comment: So you want `(a__name=X OR b_name=X OR c_name = X) AND ( a__value=1 OR b_value=1 or c_value=1)` or do you want `(a__name=X AND a_value=1) OR (b_name=X and b_value=1) OR (c_name=X AND c_value=1)`?

Comment: That would be a more complex query than I want to do. It is actually very simple case of `a__name=X AND a__value=1`. But I was wondering if it would be possible to do it with url parameters via filterset.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You'll need to create a new filter that handles the `name`, `val` pair on a *single* `Food` object that is related to a given `Component`:

```
class FoodComponentFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        strs = value.split(',')
        if len(strs) != 2:
            raise Exception
        return qs.filter(
            food_components__in = Component.objects.filter(
                name=strs[0],
                value=float(strs[1])
            )
        )
```

Instantiate this in the `FoodFilter`:

```
class FoodFilter(filters.FilterSet):
   component_food_pair = FoodComponentFilter(name='dummy_field')
   [...]
   class Meta:
        model = Food
        fields = ('component_food_pair',[...])
```

Then, use it like:

```
?component_food_pair=Foo,42.0
```

Comment: Thanks! Had to tweek a bit the qs.filter
`return qs.filter(`
   `food_components__in = Food.objects.filter(`
    `food_components__name=strs[0],`
    `food_components__value=float(strs[1])`
   `)`
  `)`


If you add the edit to your response I will set it as correct :)

Comment: Oops. I had a giant bug.  The nested filter should be of model kind `Component`, not `Food`.  Previously I was filtering `Components`'s based on `Food`'s `id`'s -- very wrong.  Added the `float` conversion.